# ExcelJS - How to handle "computed columns" with addRowsAsync

Tags: excel, excel-addins, exceljs

I'm using the ExcelJs API with `addRowsAsync()` and `deleteAllDataValuesAsync()`. ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/javascript/api/office/office.tablebinding?view=office-js))

If the user creates some "computed columns" in the Excel sheet, which enlarge the size of the table (e.g.: a new column with the value of the first column + 1), when I want add new data to the table, how should I handle the "computed" column/s?

```
let excelTable = currentWorksheet.tables.getItemOrNullObject(tableName)
  excelTable.rows.load("values")
  excelTable.columns.load("values")

  return context.sync().then(() => {
    if (excelTable.isNullObject) {
      excelTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add(tableRange, true)
      excelTable.name = tableName
      excelTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [excelHeaders]

      return context.sync().then(() => {
        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(
          tableName,
          Office.BindingType.Table,
          { id: tableName },
          function(result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
              Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(
                tableName,
                null,
                (asyncResult: any) => {
                  var binding = asyncResult.value
                  binding.addRowsAsync(_excelData)
                }
              )
            } else {
              Debug.error("Error:", result.error.message)
            }
          }
        )
      })
    } else {
      const tableRows = excelTable.rows.items.length
      const tableColumns = excelTable.columns.items.length
      const dataRows = _excelData.length
      const dataColumns = _excelData[0].length

      Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(
        tableName,
        null,
        (asyncResult: any) => {
          var binding = asyncResult.value
          binding.deleteAllDataValuesAsync()
          binding.addRowsAsync(_excelData)
        }
      )
    }

    excelTable.getRange().format.autofitColumns()
    excelTable.getRange().format.autofitRows()

    return context.sync()
  })
```

Using **Excel for Windows**, the new rows aren't added to the table.

Differenly happens if I use **Excel Online**: the rows are added and the computed column is correctly left "untouched".

Is it a bug of the API?
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance,
Andrea